# salesforce integration with java using REST API

Tags: rest-api, community, java

help me out to go forward in salesforce integration with java using REST API.

These are the steps i came across and unable to find the way.

1. Post a request to login.salesforce.com through REST client using my client_id and client_secret and username and password along with user's security token.

`https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token?grant_type=password&client_id{}&client_secret={}&username={}&password={}{}`

I got the response from salesforce along with access_token as follows :

```
{
id: "https://login.salesforce.com/id/{}"
issued_at: "{}"
token_type: "Bearer"
instance_url: "{}"
signature: "{}"
access_token: "{}"
}
```

2. Till now i am getting proper response. Now i am using the curl operation to get the available objects with the instance_url and access_token.

`curl https://{}.salesforce.com/services/data/v31.0/ -H "Authorization: Bearer {access_token}"`

Here i am getting the response as follows :

```
[{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]
```

Same response getting for different versions and for different instance_url.

Can you please shed some light on this issue and help me???

Comment: Are you literally using "Bearer: {}" as your authorization in the CURL command? Because sessionID should be something like a 112 character string.

Comment: No Doug B. I am passing the access_token like this : 
"Authorization: Bearer 00090sdsad\!KAgaraKa7887dsaasdA_3242Fdsda"

Comment: If you repeat step 1 and use the new access token, does it work?

Comment: No.. If i repeat the step1 the access_token will be updated/changed. I have used that updated token in the curl command but still i am getting the same response. I even tried with adv. REST client extension in chrome also but the response was same.

Comment: Not 100% sure if this is helpful, but i've just tried doing the same curl with our SF instance and it worked fine... I only had to change double quotes into single quotes around the header string because my token included exclamation point:

curl https://na10.salesforce.com/services/data/v31.0/ -H 'Authorization: Bearer 00DF0000000gR6k!...WS'

Comment: i've given a try with the single quote also... like this
curl https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/data/v31.0 -H 'Authorization Bearer 00900GFDA00!AkohFGSD789....S7'
But resulted same..

Comment: is it a typo or you've missed the colon right after the word Authorization:  'Authorization Bearer 00900GFDA00!AkohFGSD789....S7' ?

Comment: Hello antonlitvinenko.. I forgot to add that : in the comment... In fact, it was like
-H 'Authorization: Bearer 009900DDASAkn........'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a long trial, i succeeded in getting the proper response.

Hit through the rest-client chrome extension by passing URL and giving the 
Authorization: Bearer 00D9..........................................................Daar787@asU
in the headers list would give you the result as a response.

Comment: Hi I am trying to do  integration of salesforce with Java using Reat Api using the follwing link but i did not find the proper files on the  Java side project set up with the links given in this documentation ( https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Getting_Started_with_the_Force.com_REST_API ) , Could you please share the documentation you followed to implement this.